# Spark-Cassandra connector data reading

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm having cluster of Cassandra nodes with Spark worker on each node machine. For communication I'm using Datastax Spark-Cassasndra connector. Does the Datastax connector have optimisation for reading of data from Cassandra node by worker in same machine or exists some dataflow betweens machines?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/cassandra-and-spark-optimizing-russell-spitzer-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It indeed does.

It is explained in this document.
http://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/cassandra-and-spark-optimizing-russell-spitzer-1

Hope this helps!